# Can I highlight broken hyperlinks in Google Sheets?

Tags: xml, google-sheets

Specifically, I have a column containing thousands of automatically generated URLs pointing to individual images hosted on AWS S3. Many are existing images; many are not.

**Is there a way that I can highlight or otherwise point out those links that do not lead to an existing image?**

Non-existent images have the following displayed when viewed:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.
The document tree is shown below.
_____________________________________________________________

<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>[sting of numbers]</RequestId>
  <HostId>[string of many characters]</HostId>
</Error>
```

Currently, I am (very tediously) hovering over each link one by one using the [Thumbnail Zoom Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/thumbnail-zoom-plus/) plugin for Firefox. It will either display the image I'm looking for, or it will display an error icon. This works, but it is far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the URL's in a single column (say col A) you can use the =arrayformula(image("A:A")) formula in spreadsheet to display the actual image.

Otherwise you could also use a column for =iferror(if(IMPORTDATA(A1)="", "no image", "image"), "no image").